# Primitive Technology - Production of NaOH

Tags: acid-base, extraction

We need to produce NaOH with primitive Technology. This is Part 1 of my Gilligan's Island Challenge series ([Part 2](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/120033/primitive-technology-extract-sio2-na2so3-from-ash)). You are stuck on an island with access to a beach, a forest, a river, a lake, and a surface vein of coal.

I realize it can be made from $\ce{NaHCO3 + Ca(OH)2}$, and a person in a primitive technology scenario would be able to make some soda ash, but is there another way? $\ce{NaHCO3}$ might be tough to acquire in substantial quantities without access to a trona mine.

Would adding $\ce{NaCl}$ to a highly basic solution of, say, lime cause $\ce{NaOH}$ to form? If so, could it be extracted? Assume electricity is hard to come by.

Comment: No. Why would it? CaCl2 is soluble just fine, hence no reaction.

Comment: How about sodium sulfate instead of NaCl? The wikipedia article on it shows it occurs naturally at various locations.

Comment: Ca(OH) 2 would be pretty easy to make, could that be substituted?

Comment: I like this Gilligan's Island Challenge! This is an important question: without lye, there would be no lutefisk or hominy! Lye, especially KOH, but also some NaOH, was traditionally obtained by leaching wood ashes. As stated in wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lutefisk), birch ash "contains high amounts of potassium carbonate and bicarbonate".

Comment: @EdV - Wow! That is exactly the answer I was looking for.